# Ambari1.7 Hadoop 3.0 cluster Ganglia monitor install fails on centos 6.X

Tags: python, hadoop, rrdtool, ambari

**We are trying to install ganglia service on hadoop cluster node  using ambari agent  python script.**

**Getting following error:**

```
Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-rrdtool-1.4.5' returned 1. Error: Nothing to do
```

Detail Error:

```
stderr: 
2015-07-01 10:28:11,046 - Error while executing command 'install':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 123, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/PHD/2.0.6/services/GANGLIA/package/scripts/ganglia_monitor.py", line 33, in install
    self.install_packages(env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 188, in install_packages
    Package(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 149, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 115, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 40, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 36, in install_package
    shell.checked_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 36, in checked_call
    return _call(command, logoutput, True, cwd, env, preexec_fn, user, wait_for_finish, timeout, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-rrdtool-1.4.5' returned 1. Error: Nothing to do
 stdout:
2015-07-01 10:28:08,067 - Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/;     curl -kf -x "" --retry 10     http://R/resources//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip'] {'environment': ..., 'not_if': 'test -e /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip', 'ignore_failures': True, 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,079 - Skipping Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/;     curl -kf -x "" --retry 10     http://FQDN/resources//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK7.zip'] due to not_if
2015-07-01 10:28:08,080 - Group['hadoop'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,081 - Modifying group hadoop
2015-07-01 10:28:08,096 - Group['nobody'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,097 - Modifying group nobody
2015-07-01 10:28:08,111 - Group['users'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,112 - Modifying group users
2015-07-01 10:28:08,126 - Group['nagios'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,126 - Modifying group nagios
2015-07-01 10:28:08,141 - Group['knox'] {'ignore_failures': False}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,141 - Modifying group knox
2015-07-01 10:28:08,157 - User['nobody'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'nobody']}
2015-007-01 10:28:08,157 - Modifying user nobody
2015-070-01 10:28:08,169 - User['mapred'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,170 - Modifying user mapred
2015-07-01 10:28:08,182 - User['nagios'] {'gid': 'nagios', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,183 - Modifying user nagios
2015-07-01 10:28:08,195 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'users']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,195 - Modifying user ambari-qa
2015-07-01 10:28:08,208 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,208 - Modifying user zookeeper
2015-07-01 10:28:08,221 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'users']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,221 - Modifying user tez
2015-07-01 10:28:08,233 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,234 - Modifying user hdfs
2015-07-01 10:28:08,246 - User['knox'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,246 - Modifying user knox
2015-07-01 10:28:08,259 - User['yarn'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'ignore_failures': False, 'groups': [u'hadoop']}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,260 - Modifying user yarn
2015-07-01 10:28:08,272 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,273 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa 2>/dev/null'] {'not_if': 'test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000'}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,285 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa 2>/dev/null'] due to not_if
2015-07-01 10:28:08,285 - Directory['/etc/hadoop/conf.empty'] {'owner': 'root', 'group': 'root', 'recursive': True}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,286 - Link['/etc/hadoop/conf'] {'not_if': 'ls /etc/hadoop/conf', 'to': '/etc/hadoop/conf.empty'}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,297 - Skipping Link['/etc/hadoop/conf'] due to not_if
2015-07-01 10:28:08,313 - File['/etc/hadoop/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs'}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,327 - Repository['PHD-3.0'] {'base_url': 'http://FQDN/PHD-3.0.0.0', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'PHD', 'main'], 'repo_template': 'repo_suse_rhel.j2', 'repo_file_name': 'PHD', 'mirror_list': None}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,336 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/PHD.repo'] {'content': Template('repo_suse_rhel.j2')}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,337 - Repository['PHD-UTILS-1.1.0.20'] {'base_url': 'http://FQDN/PHD-UTILS-1.1.0.20', 'action': ['create'], 'components': [u'PHD-UTILS', 'main'], 'repo_template': 'repo_suse_rhel.j2', 'repo_file_name': 'PHD-UTILS', 'mirror_list': None}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,341 - File['/etc/yum.repos.d/PHD-UTILS.repo'] {'content': Template('repo_suse_rhel.j2')}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,341 - Package['unzip'] {}
2015-07-01 10:28:08,681 - Skipping installing existent package unzip
2015-07-01 10:28:08,682 - Package['curl'] {}
2015-07-01 10:28:09,024 - Skipping installing existent package curl
2015-07-01 10:28:09,024 - Package['distro-select'] {}
2015-07-01 10:28:09,373 - Skipping installing existent package distro-select
2015-07-01 10:28:09,374 - Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/ ;   curl -kf -x ""   --retry 10 http://FQDN/resources//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz'] {'environment': ..., 'not_if': 'test -e /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java', 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-07-01 10:28:09,385 - Skipping Execute['mkdir -p /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts/ ;   curl -kf -x ""   --retry 10 http://FQDN:8080/resources//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz -o /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz'] due to not_if
2015-07-01 10:28:09,386 - Execute['mkdir -p /usr/jdk64 ; cd /usr/jdk64 ; tar -xf /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1'] {'not_if': 'test -e /usr/jdk64/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java', 'path': ['/bin', '/usr/bin/']}
2015-07-01 10:28:09,397 - Skipping Execute['mkdir -p /usr/jdk64 ; cd /usr/jdk64 ; tar -xf /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/tmp/AMBARI-artifacts//jdk-7u67-linux-x64.tar.gz > /dev/null 2>&1'] due to not_if
2015-07-01 10:28:09,555 - Package['httpd'] {}
2015-07-01 10:28:09,899 - Skipping installing existent package httpd
2015-07-01 10:28:09,900 - Package['python-rrdtool-1.4.5'] {}
2015-07-01 10:28:10,246 - Installing package python-rrdtool-1.4.5 ('/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-rrdtool-1.4.5')
2015-07-01 10:28:11,046 - Error while executing command 'install':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 123, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/PHD/2.0.6/services/GANGLIA/package/scripts/ganglia_monitor.py", line 33, in install
    self.install_packages(env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 188, in install_packages
    Package(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 149, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 115, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/__init__.py", line 40, in action_install
    self.install_package(package_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/package/yumrpm.py", line 36, in install_package
    shell.checked_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 36, in checked_call
    return _call(command, logoutput, True, cwd, env, preexec_fn, user, wait_for_finish, timeout, path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
Fail: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install python-rrdtool-1.4.5' returned 1. Error: Nothing to do-----
```

**Any Help would be much appreciated**

Comment: It looks like it's having trouble installing python-rrdtool using yum. To get a better idea of what's going wrong just try installing that particular package from the command line. Run command: sudo yum -v install python-rrdtool-1.4.5 to see if it does indeed error and what the specific error is and troubleshoot accordingly. If you're unsure how to troubleshoot the error update your question with the output of the yum command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have HDP-UTILS.repo in your /etc/yum.repos.d/ and retry.